# Why do I have to reinstall dependencies using pip instead of Poetry when using Celery

Tags: python, celery, python-poetry

I tried to start my Celery worker like this `celery -A backend worker -l info` but I got this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework'
```

I'm using Poetry and I already have my virtual environment activated and it was included in my `pyproject.toml`

```
python = "^3.9"
aiohttp = "^3.7.4"
six = "^1.16.0"
Django = "^3.2.5"
djangorestframework = "^3.12.4"
python-dotenv = "^0.19.0"
psycopg2 = "^2.9.1"
celery = "^5.1.2"
redis = "^3.5.3"
```

So then I ran `pip install djangorestframework` and the error went away but I got a new error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

Which I also solved with `pip install psycopg2`, but it doesn't make sense why I have to do this for Celery to work? Before I could start my Django backend without this so I know my dependencies are there and from `pyproject.toml` as well

Comment: Are you calling `celery -A backend worker -l info` from within your poetry environment? i.e. `poetry run celery -A backend worker -l info` or `poetry shell` to activate the virtual environment first?

Comment: `poetry shell` to activate the virtual environment first

Comment: The former seems to work, but why?

Comment: I'm not certain, but depending on what program or terminal you're using to drive `poetry shell` it may not actually be activating the environment properly. See https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/571